# Jackson jsonGenerator generate Elasticsearch query DSL

Tags: elasticsearch, jackson, rest-client

I am new to Elasticserach and Jackson Json. There is a simple query(search index by a country) I try to use JsonGenerator,

```
"{\n" +
    "    \"query\" : {\n" +
    "    \"match\": { \"exporting_country\":\"" + countryCode + "\"} \n" +
    "} \n"+
    "}"
```

JsonGenerator code,

```
        JsonGenerator jGenerator = jfactory.createGenerator(outputStream);

        jGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jGenerator.writeFieldName("query");

        jGenerator.writeStartObject();

        jGenerator.writeFieldName("match");
        jGenerator.writeStringField("exporting_country", countryCode);

        jGenerator.writeEndObject();
        jGenerator.writeEndObject();
        jGenerator.close();
```

it throws out an error:

```
Can not write a field name, expecting a value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a call to `writeStartObject`:

```
    JsonGenerator jGenerator = jfactory.createGenerator(outputStream);

    jGenerator.writeStartObject();
    jGenerator.writeFieldName("query");

    jGenerator.writeStartObject();

    jGenerator.writeFieldName("match");
    jGenerator.writeStartObject();             <--- add this
    jGenerator.writeStringField("exporting_country", countryCode);
    jGenerator.writeEndObject();               <--- and this

    jGenerator.writeEndObject();
    jGenerator.writeEndObject();
    jGenerator.close();
```